# Detect collision between svg path and svg text

Tags: svg, path, collision-detection

Suppose I have a svg path and a piece of text. I want to figure out where they intersect. I'm not really sure where to start, because the svg path's getBBox() function does not help.

Where should I start?

Comment: When you say "where they intersect", what do you mean?  Do you mean which characters the line touches, or the exact places the line touches any of the glyph outlines, or just simply whether they touch each other at all?

Comment: where they touch each other at all - or, to simplify, when the bounding box of the text touches the line.

Answer (score 3):

You have the text bounding box via `getBBox()`.  Unfortunately, as you may have already discovered, that is not a *tight* bounding box of the glyphs.  It includes the full descender and ascender heights of the font.  However it should get you a reasonable approximation.

The next step is to determine where the path hits the bounding box.  Getting a perfect mathematical solution is very hard, but there are iterative approaches that are much easier and give good results.

Path elements have a [couple of DOM functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement) that can help: `getTotalLength()` and `getPointAtLength()`.  You can step along the path from 0 to the path length, calling `getPointAtLength()`, until the point returned is inside the text bbox.

If you want to get more accurate and determine which character in the text touches the line, there are some [DOM functions on SVG text elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#InterfaceSVGTextContentElement) that should be useful.  For instance, `getExtentOfChar(n) returns the bounds of the nth character in the text.